# Erasing Window Background

Tags: winapi, background, erase

As far as I understand, Windows makes a division of labor with regards to the (re)painting of a given window; the division into background erasure and foreground painting. The `WM_ERASEBKGND`message is sent to prepare an invalidated portion of a given window for painting, and usually this preparation consists of erasing the background so the actual painting can commence of a clean canvas. It seems to me this message is always sent when Windows invalidates part of a given window (and so is basically always sent in conjunction with a `WM_PAINT` message being posted). Whenever the application itself invalidates (part of) a given window, the last argument to the `InvalidateRect` function specifies whether a `WM_ERASEBKGND`is to be sent or not. So I wrote a small program to test my assumptions, but its behavior eludes me a little. This is said program:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hwInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = {0};

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH); 
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

                                        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);

    // Run the message loop.

    MSG msg = {0};
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int eb_count = 0; // counts number of WM_ERASEBKGND messages

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        RECT rect;

        wchar_t text[40]; 
        wsprintf(text, L"Number of WM_ERASEBKGND messages: %i\n", eb_count);

        GetClientRect(hwnd, &rect);
        DrawText(hdc, text, -1, &rect, DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;

    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN: // repaint whenever RBUTTONDOWN
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        return 0;

    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        eb_count++;
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I am handling `WM_ERASEBKGND` in the window procedure (it is a case in my switch), so it should not be passed to the default window procedure. However, I don't do any actual background erasing (I simply increment a static variable) and I return 0 to indicate that no erasing actually took place. It seems to me that in this program, the background should never get erased. This does, however, happen in two distinct instances.

Whenever I maximize the window, the background of the invalid portion does get erased with the class background brush. But how is this possible? The window procedure certainly does no such thing upon receiving a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message.

A similar thing happens whenever `DrawText` repaints its string. I would expect that the incrementing numbers would get painted on top of eachother (leading to an illegible mess, of course). So it seems the 'DrawText' function also somehow erases the background of the rectangle in which it paints its string.

My last question pertains to my assumption that a `WM_ERASEBKGND` message is sent whenever Windows invalidates part of a window. I noticed that whenever the window is covered by another window and subsequently uncovered, no `WM_ERASEBKGND` message seems to be sent. Does this mean my assumption is wrong?
Sorry for the long read, but any and all help in answering these questions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See documentaion for [`WM_ERASEBKGND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055(v=vs.85).aspx) - You are not erasing background and you return 0 in response to `WM_ERASEBKGND`. Maybe you want `case WM_ERASEBKGND:break;` or just leave that out. Or do the background painting in `WM_PAINT`

Comment: If you want to prevent default background drawing, do nothing in the code that handles `WM_ERASEBKGND` and return a non-zero value to tell Windows that you have handled it. In this case you should do all painting (including background drawing) in `WM_PAINT`. To prevent `DrawText()` from clearing background, call `SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT)` before.

Comment: @zett42 Does it really matter whether I return 0 or a non-zero value? As far as I can tell the only real difference is that when I return 0, the `fErase` flag of `PAINTSTRUCT` will be set to `TRUE`. If i return a non-zero value, the flag will be set to `FALSE`. Other than that, there's no real difference; in either case what really matters is what actually happens during `WM_ERASEBKGND`, which in my program is nothing. So no matter what I return, in either case I can handle all painting in `WM_PAINT`, right?

Comment: The [reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't say that the `PAINTSTRUCT::fErase` flag is the only thing that is affected by the return value of `WM_ERASEBKGND`. Note the word "typically". So I would play it safely and always return `TRUE`.

Answer (score 4):

> ... my assumption that a WM_ERASEBKGND message is sent whenever Windows invalidates part of a window. I noticed that whenever the window is covered by another window and subsequently uncovered, no WM_ERASEBKGND message seems to be sent ...

That's because, as of Vista and later, we have the [Desktop Window Manager (DWM)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa969540.aspx) lurking away in the, erm, background.  This buffers the contents of all the on-screen windows so that Windows doesn't need to issue WM_ERASEBKGND or WM_PAINT requests when part of one is uncovered - it can just copy the so-called back-buffer back to the screen.

[Parts of] windows do still get invalidated - either by you or the OS - but not as often as they used to be back in the XP days.  Try minimising and restoring a window for example - then it has to be redrawn.  When you do that, the DWM probably throws away the back-buffer to save memory while the window is minimised.

Apart from that, what the others said in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that explains it. Can you also explain why the background of the invalid portion of the window still gets erased with the class background brush when I maximize the window?

Comment: Return TRUE from WM_ERASEBKGND rather than 0 (as already explained - twice).  Or set the class background brush to GetStockObject (NULL_BRUSH).

Comment: No need for the passive-aggressive response. My question is not concerned with the how, as much as it is with the why. I can easily get the same result as the `NULL_BRUSH` by simply not setting a class background brush, but this was not the essence of my question at all. Also, it does not matter whether I return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, in both instances the same behavior occurs. Hence my earlier comment that the only thing that seems to be affected by the return value is the `fErase` field of `PAINTSTRUCT`.

Comment: Sorry, I have re-read the comments above and I owe you an apology.  It does look like WM_ERASEBKGND is indeed not behaving as documented.  Did you see zett42's link below? I think that's the key to this.  Now that I stop to think about it, I had a similar experience to you a while back, and I think, these days, that Windows might paint the window with the background brush all on its own, for reasons explained in the article linked to.  My memory is hazy, but there was a time when the exposed edges of my windows were painted black (until my drawing code caught up) until I sorted my brushes out.

Comment: Voted you up, to atone for my rudeness (and because I like the question).

Answer (score 2):

As per the answer by @Paul Sanders most recently the Desktop Window Manager is a process that does, actually, cache the contents of windows so it can perform a blend effects when composing the desktop, which means that your Window does not always get repainted in the way it did in earlier editions of Windows.

Prior to that, the move from a co-operatively multitasked to a multithreaded OS (This painting model was in the Windows 3.0 API) introduced some race conditions that, iirc, Windows would try and cover up by doing a pre-emptive background-brush fill in some cases when some process changed the visibility of another processes window. This is what you see when you maximise the window.

Your call to `DrawText` is working, because `DrawText` - by default - does its own background erase - you need to call `SetBkMode` passing in the `TRANSPARENT` flag to render just the font.

Comment: Interesting OldNewThing read: [The white flash](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040123-00/?p=40943/)